# Camel AWS-S3 - Not all bytes were read from the S3ObjectInputStream, aborting HTTP connection

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-camel, apache-camel-aws

I am using camel-aws to poll a file onto the remote S3 bucket to check if it has arrived or not.
I am not interested in the content of the file.

```
from("direct:my-route").
.from("aws-s3://my.bucket?useIAMCredentials=true&useAwsKMS=true&awsKMSKeyId=my-key-id&deleteAfterRead=false&operation=listObjects&includeBody=false&prefix=test1/etmp_xi_inbound.xml")
.log(" File detected: ${header.CamelAwsS3Key}")
.end();
```

I have set the includeBody to false to not to read the content of the file however I am getting below warning:

```
WARN  c.a.s.s.i.S3AbortableInputStream - Not all bytes were read from the S3ObjectInputStream, aborting HTTP connection. This is likely an error and may result in sub-optimal behavior. Request only the bytes you need via a ranged GET or drain the input stream after use.
```

Comment: What version of Camel are you using?

Comment: Camel version being used - 2.22.0

Comment: Thanks I have logged a ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-14386

Comment: Its a WARN logging so you still get the message, but yeah it would be nice  to get it fixed

Answer (score 0):

Do you have autoCloseBody set to true? It seems that potentially in newer versions of Camel that they auto close the s3 connection and so having autoCloseBody=true means you are trying to close an already closed connection hence causing the error.